# pentaho report display multiple sections

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I'm new to pantaho and please forgive me if I ask stupid question.
All I am trying to do is split my report in 2 sections and I could not figure out how.

For example, I have a query returning a 5 column table. Generally if I put those data into the pentaho report, it would be something like this:

```
c1      c2      c3      c4       c5
data    data   data    data     data
data    data   data    data     data
```

but now what I want is to split the table in 2, one by one:

```
section1
c1     c2      c3
data   data    data
data   data    data

section2
c1     c4      c5
data   data    data
data   data    data
```

Am I able to achieve that?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sub-report, and achieve this.
learn how to use sub-report, use the same query in sub-report and you can achieve your result.

Comment: By using sub-report, I have to do the same query twice, right?

Comment: Yes you have to use the same query.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might need to add a column in your data base called 'Section' where you insert either 'Section1' or 'Section2' for each row. Then add a group on sections.
Check out this video on how to add a group: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cmuwadNK_0w
I don't know if it is the best solution, hope it works.